# jscript code to C#

Tags: c#, jscript, wsh

Any good jscript code converter to C#
I want to convert this piece of code into C#
This code is for generating admin password base from device MAC Address

```
    <script language="jscript">
    var add=[12,2,17,5,16,31,28,10,16,20,22,1];
    var subst={58:122,59:121,60:120,61:119,62:118,63:117,64:116,91:115,92:114,93:113,94:112,45:111,96:110};

    function generatePassword(input){
    var inputMac=input.replace(/:/g,"").toUpperCase();
    var macPassword="";
if((inputMac.search(/^[A-F0-9]{12}$/)==-1) || (inputMac =="000000000000")){
    return macPassword="invalid"}
else{
    var b;
    var a;
    var c="";
    for(b=0;b<12;b++){
        a=inputMac.charCodeAt(b)+add[b];
        if(subst[a]){
            a=subst[a]
        }
        c+=String.fromCharCode(a)
    }
    return macPassword="2008"+c+"";
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: All function used above are present in c#, have u tried coding yourself!?

Comment: what's equivalent of this on C#? I am confuse on this two parts I'm trying to code it. var add=[12,2,17,5,16,31,28,10,16,20,22,1];
    var subst={58:122,59:121,60:120,61:119,62:118,63:117,64:116,91:115,92:114,93:113,94:112,45:111,96:110};

Comment: well first one as i can see is normal int array, and dont u know whats that in jscript?

Comment: I have a little knowledge of jscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any converters from JScript to C#, only the other way around. And I don't even have a very good opinion of those. IMO, there are too many language and framework specifics for "transpiling" to work really well.

I don't know where you found the code you posted, since based on the comments, you don't really know JScript. I hope you're better at C#, so that you'll at least understand the converted function:

```
public string GeneratePassword(string input)
{
    var add= new byte[] {12,2,17,5,16,31,28,10,16,20,22,1};
    var subst = new Dictionary<byte, byte> {{58,122},{59,121},{60,120},{61,119},{62,118},{63,117},{64,116},{91,115},{92,114},{93,113},{94,112},{45,111},{96,110}};

    var inputMac = input.Replace(":", "").ToUpperInvariant();
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(inputMac, "^[A-F0-9]{12}$") || (inputMac == "000000000000"))
    {
        return "invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        var c="";
        for(var b = 0; b < 12; b++)
        {
            var a = (byte)((byte)inputMac[b] + add[b]);
            if(subst.ContainsKey(a))
            {
                a=subst[a];
            }
            c += (char)a;
        }
        return "2008" + c;
    }
}
```

The C# code can be further improved, but I wanted to keep it as close to the original as possible, so that you can learn about the differences in specific constructs and do it yourself in the future, instead of just using the converted code as is.

Just curious: what are you going to use this function for?

Comment: thanks. It works. I know how to convert the rest, the lines that I am confused are tha first two line, I don't know what exactly is that in C#.